# Bootstrap Validator - validating only partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, bootstrapvalidator

Again a question about the Bootstrap validator. I am using this plugin: [Validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator)

I have a large `<form>` with several groups, which we name a "mask". Each mask consists of several "fields". Each field can be normal `<input>`, `<select>`, etc. Each of those fields has specific rules like field_1 can have `required` and `data-minLength="5"`, field_2 can have `maxlength="30"`, etc.

Wanted behaviour: If one of those groups / masks is valid in itself, enable the submit button again so i can partially send the form, don't wait until all parts of the form are filled. Problem: The submit button is completely disabled until i have fulfilled all validator rules from the COMPLETE form, which is not what i want. If 1 or more groups out of the whole form is valid in itself, activate the submit button.

What i tried:

```
$("#inputForm").on("change", function () {
        $("#inputForm").find("*[id^=mask_]").each(function() {
            var valid = true;
            $(this).find("input[id^=field_], select[id^=field_]").each(function() {
                if(!$(this).val()) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            });

            if(valid) {
                $("#inputForm").find(":submit").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#inputForm").prop("novalidate", false)
            }
        });
    });
```

How to do that? My code does reach the `if(valid)` clause, but won't reactivate the submit button... Also: Don't autosend it, if one group is valid by calling `submit()` on the form, only activate the button in order to make the user able to send it now.

Thanks!

Comment: Your wanted behavior conflicts with bootstrap's form validation.  Bootstrap wont let you submit the form until all items have validated.  Curious, why would you want the user to be able to submit a partially completed form?  If the form is really long, e.g. resume, taxes, etc, you might consider breaking it into steps (each having its own form tag) and having the user do each one, saving the form data via ajax before they can move on to the next form.

Comment: Yes the form is extremly long, no i can't break it up. Since the data / input fields is already divided into several groups, we figured it would be best if we just let the users send it partially. This is needed for several reasons in the whole project. Is there no way to let the validator validate stuff and give back the feedback but still let me use the submit button?...

Comment: You're wanting bootstrap to both to enforce form validation and not enforce form validation. Those goals are in conflict.  You could do an ajax request inside your if(valid) condition so the user's information could be temporarily saved until they've corrected all the errors.

Comment: No, i only want the validator to display errors to the user with has-feedback and those error spans. Nothing else for this form. There must be a way to visually validate and still be able to click the submit button?

Comment: You're wanting bootstrap to both to enforce form validation and not enforce form validation.  You cant tell bootstrap to require a form field and still be able to submit the form.  If you can provide your full code, maybe a JS fiddle example, you might be able to get help writing something custom to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Already sort of done. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after 2 hours of searching and trying, this is what i ended up doing:

1. Throw in the the option disable, set to false:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#inputForm").validator({
               disable: false
           });
   });
   ```

This will guarantee, that the submit button is always clickable. However: this will still result in calling the `onSubmit()` function of the validator, saying "stop no, that isn't valid yet".

2. Added the following to the min.js to ensure JUST FOR THIS VERY FORM, ignore the `onSubmit()` validation to make it able to send, even though it is not 100% valid yet.

   ```
   c.prototype.onSubmit=function(a){if(c.attr("id")!="inputForm"){this.validate(),(this.isIncomplete()||this.hasErrors())&&a.preventDefault()}}
   ```

This will let the validator ignore the `onSubmit()` on the form #inputForm.

**Caution:** Don't use this normally, because this is of course not what a validator is for. This reduces the js validator to just a graphical validator simply saying "hey here is something wrong, but ok, if you want to sent it anyway, do it". If doing so, you must catch that stuff server side, like we did.